# How can I make SublimeText show subdirs under folder_include_patterns?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

I have a SublimeText3 project which I use to show particular folders in the sidebar. This works, however subdirectories of the folders in `folder_include_pattern` are not visible in the project (they're obviously there if I open the project as a folder instead).

```
node_modules
  my-module
    ('test' should be here but is not shown)
  my-other-module
    ('test' should be here but is not shown)
```

Here is my .project file:

```
{
  "folders": [
    {
      "path": "node_modules",
      "folder_include_patterns": [
        "my-module",
        "my-other-module"
      ]
    },
    {
      "path": "."
    }
  ]
}
```

**How can I show all the subdirs of the directories in `folder_include_patterns`?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved it: **subdir names must also be in `folder_include_patterns`**. Eg, to include `/node_modules/my-module/test`, I needed:

```
 {
  "folders": [
    {
      "path": "node_modules",
      "folder_include_patterns": [
        "my-module",
        "my-other-module",
        "test"
      ]
    },
    {
      "path": "."
    }
  ]
}
```

**2018 updae:** note if you're reading this in 2018, and want to do this for `node_modules`, the best way to handle monorepos (where you have some of your own modules included in the project) is via [yarn workspaces](https://yarnpkg.com/blog/2017/08/02/introducing-workspaces/)